# ¿xrange es a bucles for, lo que yield es a bucles while?

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, while, yield

Estoy comenzando a programar recién, y un par de conceptos que en particular me intrigaron, es el denominado xrange(n) utilizado en los bucles for, y el denominado yield utilizado en los bucles while.

Entiendo que ambos son para retornar su propio tipo de dato, el xrange-type siempre ocupará la misma cantidad de memoria (RAM) sin importar el tamaño del rango y el yield funciona similar a un return pero la diferencia importante es que conserva la iteración. y así no devolver una lista completa, si no solamente almacenar en la memoria el valor que van retornando

Entonces mi pregunta es, ¿Son comparables dichas funciones en los bucles respectivos?.

```py
def contador(max):
    n=0
    while n < max:
            yield n
            n=n+1

mycont = contador(5)

for i in mycont:
    print(i)

# print(mycont)
El resultado de correr lo anterior es

0
1
2
3
4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> xrange(5)
xrange(5)
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print i
... 
0
1
2
3
4
>>> for i in xrange(5):
...     print i 
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Agradezco sus respuestas y/o correciónes, sigo aprendiendo día con día.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De la que comencé a leer tu pregunta me pareció que andabas bastante confundido, al querer equiparar `xrange()` que es una función (o más propiamente hablando una función generadora) con `yield`, que es un *keyword*, es decir, una palabra reservada del lenguaje. Pero tras terminar de leerla creo entender por dónde vas.

Lo primero que habría que aclarar es que `xrange()`  es cosa de Python2. En Python3 no existe, y por una buena razón, relacionada con tu pregunta. Así que vamos por partes.

## `range()` en Python2

Esta función en Python2 te retorna una lista. Las dos líneas siguientes son equivalentes para Python2:

```
numeros = range(10)
numeros = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

En muchas ocasiones `range()` se usa para iterar por los enteros consecutivos, como en:

```
for i in range(10):
   # Acceder por ejemplo al elemento i-esimo de una lista
```

Aunque en python no es necesario usar ese patrón para recorrer una lista (pues puedes poner `for dato in lista:` para obtener los datos sin necesidad de acceder a ellos por su índice), este patrón no obstante era muy común entre programadores novatos que vienen del C o de Java, lenguajes en los que es habitual iterar por los índices.

No obstante, si necesitas iterar por una gran cantidad de números, como por ejemplo los 1000 primeros enteros, usar `for i in range(1000)` hacía algo aparentemente innecesario:

1. Crea una lista de 1000 elementos (con el consiguiente consumo de memoria)
2. Itera por los elementos de esa lista

A medida que el número dentro de `range()` se hace más grande, más espacio de memoria necesitaría ese `for`. Si queremos por ejemplo sumar el primer millón de números con un bucle como:

```
suma = 0
for i in range(1000000):
   suma += i
print(suma)
```

el programa requerirá primero crear la lista con un millón de elementos. ¡Ridículo!

Naturalmente es que estamos usando el patrón equivocado, ya que para sumar esos elementos podríamos usar un bucle `while` que no necesite crear lista alguna. Así:

```
suma = 0
i = 0
while i < 1000000:
   suma += i
   i += 1
```

No obstante la sintaxis del `for` era más cómoda... ¿entonces?

## Funciones generadoras

Las funciones generadoras de python vienen al rescate. Una función generadora es una función que contenga `yield`. Cuando Python encuentra que esa instrucción aparece en la función, la marca de forma especial. Su ejecución ya no es normal, sino que produce un generador. Veamos un ejemplo.

La siguiente función es un generador, que genera los números entre 0 y n:

```
def generar_numeros(n):
   i = 0
   while i < n:
     yield i
     i += 1
```

Cuando en tu programa hagas `g = generar_numeros(5)`, por ejemplo, la ejecución no es normal. Ya que Python ha detectado que esta función es *generadora*, la ejecución produce un *generador* y eso es lo que te devuelve y tenemos almacenado en `g`. Puedes comprobarlo:

```
>>> g = generar_numeros(5)
>>> g
<generator object generar_numeros at 0x7fd18fb29410>
```

Un generador es un tipo de objeto que implementa la posiblidad de iterar sobre él. Para iterar sobre un generador debes hacer `next()` sobre el mismo. En este caso `next(g)`. Entonces la función comenzará su ejecución normalmente, en nuestro caso haciendo `i=0` etc... hasta encontrar una instrucción `yield`. El valor tras `yield` es retornado como resultado del `next()` y la función queda "parada" en esa línea. La próxima vez que hagas `next(g)` se reanudará desde la línea del `yield` y continuará normalmente hasta encontrar otro `yield`, y así una y otra vez hasta que (quizás, no está obligada) en algún momento la función termine (ya porque llega al final, ya porque encuentra una instrucción `return`). En ese momento se genera una excepción `StopIteration`.

Mira:

```
>>> g = generar_numeros(5)
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> next(g)
3
>>> next(g)
4
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

## Generadores y el bucle for

Por suerte no necesitamos hacer `next()` ni tratar con la excepción `StopIteration`. Esto lo hace para nosotros el bucle `for`. Cuando haces `for variable in generador`, python va llamando a `next()` sobre el generador, recogiendo cada resultado en la `variable` que le indiques, y terminando el bucle cuando se produce `StopIteration`. Por tanto lo anterior podríamos haberlo escrito así:

```
g = generar_numeros(5)
for i in g:
   print(i)
```

Y esto imprimiría también los números del 1 al 5 que se irán generando en nuestro generador `g`. Fíjate que no se almacenan en lista alguna, de modo que ocupa la misma cantidad de memoria generar 5 números que generar un millón.

## `xrange()` en Python2

Esta función no es más que la versión "generadora" de `range()`. De hecho, nuestra simple `genera_numeros()` hace exactamente lo mismo (savo que `xrange()` permite opcionalmente especificar un número de inicio y el intervalo entre números).

## ¿Y python 3?

En python 3, muchas de las primitivas del lenguaje que retornaban listas, ahora retornan generadores, que es mucho más eficiente en términos de memoria. Así `range()` en python3 es un generador (equivalente al antiguo `xrange()`) y `xrange()` ha desaparecido.

Si por lo que fuera quisieras una lista con los números del 0 al 10 en python3, siempre puedes hacer:

```
numeros = list(range(10))
```

pues el constructor `list()` admite como parámetro un generador y en ese caso itera sobre él y crea una lista con todos los elementos retornados por éste hasta `StopIteration`.

Por tanto tenías razón en la pregunta. De algún modo están relacionados, pero **no tiene nada qué ver su uso en bucles while**. Una función generadora perfectamente podría tener dentro también un bucle for.

Comment: Muchas gracia!, justo lo lo comienzo a digerir, por lo que debe ser que aún no lo tengo muy muy en claro, pero ahora lo entiendo mejor.

Comment: @GabrielC-M Leelo varias veces :-) Y sigue haciendo experimentos, que es la mejor forma de comprender. Si tienes alguna duda más, pregúntala en comentarios y extiendo la respuesta. Cuando consideres que ésta ha resuelto tus dudas márcala como aceptada para que la pregunta no siga "abierta"